# Virtual Machine with FBCTF

Tags: linux, facebook, virtualbox

I'm trying FBCTF competition (https://github.com/facebook/fbctf)

My problem is that, when I try to add a base level, using a VBox machine, when I try to acces to this machine's network ip, I always get the FBCTF index.php.

Networks IP is 192.168.56.1, so I use nmap -p- -A 192.168.56.0/24 for scanning the box, but cant find the correct one.

Someone knows why? I'm missing something on the port scan?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already works. FBCTF is using a NAT, so all trafic is coming to the computer is being redirected to this IP.

Removing the NAT and using Bridge, solves the problem.